# Does 'bounded by convergent series' imply convergence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose we have a real series $\sum x_{n}$ which is convergent. If we have either $0<y_{n}<x_{n}$ or $x_{n}<y_{n}<0$  for all $n$ past some limit (so $|y_{n}|<|x_{n}|$, and they have the same sign), is it necessarily true that $\sum y_{n}$ is convergent? I think I can prove it if $\sum x_{n}$ is absolutely convergent, but I'm not sure about the general case.

More specifically, I'm trying to find out, given that $\sum x_{n}$ converges, whether or not $\sum x_{n}^{3}$ does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Think about taking the alternating harmonic series and making all the odd terms zero. The remaining even terms diverge like the harmonic series.

Comment: But this new series has every term positive, so $x_{n}$ and $y_{n}$ don't have the same sign.

Comment: It satisfies your condition with non-strict inequalities. I leave the strict version as an exercise for now. (You could replace the negative terms with  a convergent series, for instance.) I will try to add more details later today.

Comment: Ah, I understand now!